# Accessing output function in mian without static keyword

Tags: c#

In this code I made two output functions and one main.
When I call output function in main the program give the error.

```
using System;
public class InitArray
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] rectangular = { { 1, 3, 4 }, { 5, 2, 4 } };
        int[][] jagged = { new int[] { 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 3, 4, 5 }};  
    }

    public void OutputArray(int [,]array)
    {
        for(int row=0;row<array.GetLength(0);row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < array.GetLength(1); column++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", array[row, column]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    public void OutputArray(int [][]array)
    {
        foreach(var row in array)
        {
            foreach (var element in row)
                Console.Write("{0} ", element);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is main function and have two arrays one is jagged and other is rectangular type.

The defined function is without static keyword and I could not access in main function.

This second output function is also a non static function and this is also not access in main.

Anyone can tell me the the reason?

Comment: What's with all the different languages tagged?

Comment: Do not spam tags. This has nothing to do with Java, HTML, or ASP.NET.

Comment: Your `OutputArray()` method needs to be `static` to call it from the `Main()` method without an instance of itself, try `public static void OutputArray(...)`

Comment: Voting to close this as it's a simple problem of not making the methods static.

Comment: is it right to vote to close because "it's a simple problem"? Obviously not that simple for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

*Non-static* methods want *instance*; that's why either mark the method as `static`:

```
 public static void OutputArray(int[][] array) {  
   ...
 }

 public static void Main() {
   ...
   OutputArray(...);
   ...
 }
```

or create and provide the *instance*:

```
 public void OutputArray(int[][] array) {  
   ...
 }

 public static void Main() {
   ...

   var instance = new InitArray();

   instance.OutputArray(...);
   ...
 }
```